# What is the proper syntax for searching to see if two values in a dictionary exist?

Tags: python-3.x

Why do these two print functions return different values?  I'm trying to check to see if both 'kate' and 'joe' are values in the dictionary1.  Thank you.

```
dictionary1 = {'first': 'kate', 'second': 'mark'}

print(('joe' and 'kate') in dictionary1.values())
print(('kate' and 'joe') in dictionary1.values())
```

Comment: Consider to do `print('joe' and 'kate')` which will gives you `'kate'`. And `print('kate' and 'joe')` will gives you `'joe'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

```
print(('joe' and 'kate'))
print(('kate' and 'joe'))
```

What you want is `'joe' in d.values() and 'kate' in d.values()`.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  That makes sense.  I guess you can't use boolean operators on strings in a meaningful way.  I tried 'or' and it gave the first name.

Comment: @RyanB.Jawad There is a meaning to it. In Python the empty string `""` is considered `False` and all other strings are considered `True`. Knowing that, read this section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not.

Comment: Interesting.  hmm, that explains the behavior, but I'm not sure how that definition of 'and' and 'or' is related to the definition of 'both' or 'at least one or the other'.  I probably just need to remember that the distributive property doesn't apply to the 'in' command.

Answer (score 0):

For larger scale inclusion verification - check `numpy.isin`:

```py
import numpy as np
# for check if any of el from the list on the left are included:

np.isin(['joe', 'kate'], list(dictionary1.values())).any()

# for check if all elements from the list on the left are included:

np.isin(['joe', 'kate'], list(dictionary1.values())).all()
```

Ref. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=isin#numpy.isin